# Update dictionary with key value pair in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict1`. I want to iterate through the dict and add the output as key-value pairs in another `dict2`

```
dict1={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

dict2={}

for i in dict1:
   if i meets condition:
      add it to dict 2.
```

How would I right the last line in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
      dict2[key] = value
```